# How to get a base-3 representation of an integer using a stack?

Tags: stacks

Assuming that a stack data structure is available, how can this data structure be used to compute a representation of an integer in base three? For example, the algorithm for `printBase3` would return `12020` on input `141`.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange! I have edited your question to make it a better fit for this site, but it could still use some work. For instance, what have you tried and where did you get stuck? Do you have any doubts that are preventing you from answering this on your own? This kind of information helps the community better understand and benefit from your question. Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: This is a dump of a problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or about concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Hint: Repeatedly Compute modulus and remainder to obtain the individual digits of base3 representation. what is inconvenient about the sequence of digits generated This Way ?

Answer (score -2):

ok I think I found the solution to my question

So if n = 141, 12020 would be printed to the screen.

Solution:

```
          public static void printBase3(int n){
           if (n/3 == 0)
           System.out.print(n);
          else{
          printBase3(n/3);
          System.out.print(n%3);
          }
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't use a stack data structure. It uses the function's call stack via recursion; if this is what you meant to ask, please update the question. Thanks!